# Headless Google Auth

Tags: python

I have written this code here to upload xlsx file to google drive , everything is working fine except that it needs to be done it automatic way.
Can I pass google auth without opening the browser that googleAuth does (headless auth)
because I will put this code on a server and it will have a cron job every hour so i need it to login by itself.

```py
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()           
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)  
        
        
upload_file_list = ['traffic.xlsx']
for upload_file in upload_file_list:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': '1TpwAxTEZ3m8OiEyNOJypxXSq4W72qUAp'}]})
    gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
    gfile.Upload()
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, Google auth intends to prevent automatic login and insists on having a real human being to prove their identity. You can circumvent that with two ways:

- use a normal browser to get a valid refresh token with a very far expiration date and use that token in your application
- use selenium to fake a browser interaction with Google

Both ways will actually lower the securit of your account, because if an attacker can put their hands on your server, it will get a way to impersonate you. The former should limit the impersonation to API interaction from a registered app, while the latter will allow unlimited impersonation because the Selenium script will contain your Google password.

More details on the former way [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-authenticate-access-google-apis-using-oauth-2-0/)